# Is normal that I use a lot of structs in C++?

Tags: c++, struct

I really like using structs because they make my code cleaner, but i'm afraid that this code uses a lot of structs

```
struct action {
     int ex1 = 0;
     int ex2 = 0;
     int ex3 = 0;
     int ex4 = 0;
};

struct state { // an array of the 'struct' action
     action actions[10];
};

int main() {
     state states[10];
}
```

is that code right?

Comment: What's the intent of wrapping one array in a struct?

Comment: The code that I made is not like that, This was just an example

Comment: @Carcigenicate It's actually quite common. That said, there is a standard template for doing that (`std::array`)

Comment: @eerorika I just asked because his intent would decide whether how appropriate it is.

Comment: You can have a 3 dimensional array, which would be a good option for this specific case: `int states[10][10][4];`.

Comment: I should probably vote to close this as a question asking for opinions, but I won't. If you start this way to keep order and later find reason to reduce it with aliases or whatnot, you're having a good start - in my personal opinion.

Comment: I suggest you show the *alternative* to using such a `struct` that you have in mind, because there are some common misconceptions on what `struct`s are and aren't, but since you haven't really gone into any detail it is unclear what you consider the potential problem with your shown approach.

Comment: Case-by-case basis. If the structure makes the code easier to read, write, and maintain, the structure is justified.

Comment: @Daniel Would it, though? Without "names" for each level, it's immediately unclear what `int states[10][10][4]` means.

Answer (score 1):

You *might* want to consider some type aliases (`typedef`/`using`) instead, when you only have one member, but that's not always better.

You're probably fine.

Having a lot of types is not inherently bad.

Answer (score 0):

Let's analyze your structs:

```
struct action {
    int ex1 = 0;
    int ex2 = 0;
    int ex3 = 0;
    int ex4 = 0;
};
```

This first struct stores 4 integers.

```
struct state {
    action actions[10];
};
```

The second struct stores 10 `action`s.

```
int main() {
     state states[10];
}
```

Lastly, you create 10 `state`s.

---

It's easy to see that all you store are integers. A fast way to access integers is using an array. The first struct could be easily represented by a 4-slot array:

```
int action[4];    //action[0] = ex1; ...; action[3] = ex4;
```

The second structure is a container of 10 `action`s. It's like a bidimensional array, where, in the first dimension, you have 10 possibilities (which is the 10 `actions`), and in the second dimension, you have 4 possibilities, that are the 4 values of each `action`:

```
int state[10][4];    //state[3][2] = ex3 value from the 4-th action.
```

Lastly, you create a container with 10 states. Following the same principle, you could just add a dimension to store 10 `state`s:

```
int states[10][10][4]    //states[1][2][3] = ex4 value from the 2-th action from the 1-st state.
```

And this 3-dimensional array is all you need. It can represent your structures with less space and return your values faster.

If you want to set an action, you can just do:

```
void set_action(int ex1, int ex2, int ex3, int ex4, int action, int state){`
    states[state][action][0] = ex1;
    states[state][action][1] = ex2;
    states[state][action][2] = ex3;
    states[state][action][3] = ex4;
}
```